# If $\tilde{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of multiplicity $n$, then $A$ is a scalar matrix, where $A$ is $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\tilde{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of multiplicity $n$, then $A$ is a scalar matrix, where $A$ is $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix.

So I know that $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix} $
and that $$\det(A-\lambda I_2) = (a-λ)(c-λ) - b^2$$
However I don't really know how to proceed from there.

Comment: 1. Dont assume A is 2$\times$2. Also you know that det(A-$\lambda$I) = $(x-\lambda)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
 If $A$ has an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n$, it is the only eigenvalue of $A$, so. Furthermore real symmetric matrices are diagonalisable, so its diagonal form is $\lambda I$. Can you deduce that $A$ *is* $\lambda I$?.

*More details*:
Since is real symmetric, there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that
$$A=PDP^{-1}=P(\lambda I)P^{-1}=\lambda(PIP^{-1})=\lambda I.$$

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused on what you mean?

Comment: @ZheTian: I've added details. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of scalar matrix is a diagonal matrix which every element in the diagonal are the same, right?

I assumed that the question should be "... then $A$ is a matrix [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to a scalar matrix". But you also can abuse notation and say that, in fact, $A$ "is'' a scalar matrix by the fact that similiar matrices can represent the same linear transformation...

But, if $A$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, then $A$ is diagonalizable and there is a invertible $P$ such that $A=P DP^{-1}$, where $D=diag(\lambda,\cdots,\lambda)$.